# Is it possible in sketchup, to have one face in multiple groups/layers?

Tags: sketchup

i wana to make simple plugin in sketchup, but first of all i need to understand how sketchup works. So i played with faces, shapes, groups and layers as little kid, but there is something that blows my mind.

Is here even posible, to have one face in two groups? Or probably layer, but group will be much better. For example, i have a house which i wana to split into two zones (house + garage for example) and i know, that between this two rooms is only one wall, but it belongs to house (living part) and to garage. I would like to have garage and house (living part), but im not able to click this one in sketchup. If needed i can provide image, but i think its enough explained.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a face in a ComponentDefinition and place ComponentInstances in the model that face will exist in several places in the model. Groups are like component instances - but they are made unique when you edit them.

For more details you can read this article: http://www.thomthom.net/thoughts/2012/02/definitions-and-instances-in-sketchup/

Comment: unfortunately it isnt what i want from it :/ I need normal sketchup user, to be able to create for example house, with multiple rooms, but rooms have some shared walls, and im not sure if its even posible in sketchup...

Comment: Components are the way to re-use (share) geometry in SketchUp. I'm a little unclear to what you mean if that isn't what you are looking for. However, if this isn't a programming question you might want to post in the SketchUp forums - perhaps with some illustration of what you are looking for.

Comment: ok sorry, i will try to extend question ASAP, its a about programing, but first time i need to clarify some sketchup basics